# Node.js - Adding middlware to route doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have this route:

```
router.post("/add-user", validateUniqueEmail ,addUser);
```

And the middlware definition:

```
export const validateUniqueEmail = () => {
return body('email').custom(email => {
    return UserModel.findOne({email}).then(user => {
    if (user) {
        return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
    }
})})}
```

When I make a post request, the request is stuck.
It only works when I add parentheses to `validateUniqueEmail` in the route definition, and add `return` before `body(email)`.
What am I missing?

Comment: Becaus thats not how middleware is written. Take a look at the express.js docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

This middleware will auto go next step when not being rejected?

middleware in my experience is like:

```js
 async (req,res,next)=>{
   // checking
   if(have some issue or have no access)
    res.send("some info")
    return;

   if(everything is ok)
     mext()
  }
```

I want to suggest you do not nest your code too hard

```
async (req,res,next)=>{
    const email = req.body.email;
    // check this email
    const user = await User.findone(email);
    // email already exist
    if(user !== null){
       res.status(some number).send({ok:false,"message":"..."});
       return;
     }
     
    //everything is ok
    next();
}
```

Comment: This idn't working, tried also to add next()

Comment: Try to console log a lot, and figure out which code is executed, and which is not.